# Oracle join rows in order where order is defined differently on each table

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables

TABLE_A with columns project_id, id and load_date

and TABLE_B with columns project_id, delete_flag and delete_date

where TABLE_A.load_date is a new column and I want to populate it based on TABLE_B.delete_date for historic data. Basically, a file has been repeatedly loaded into the system and historically we didn't keep track of when it was loaded. However, each time the file is re-loaded, the previous version of it is updated in TABLE_B with a delete_date (i.e. a soft delete). The previous version just stays in TABLE_A without any changes.

I would like to populate TABLE_A.load_date based on matching projects in TABLE_B. The oldest row in TABLE_A (smallest TABLE_A.id) matches the oldest row in TABLE_B (oldest delete_date), etc. So the rows should match up if you keep picking the next one in order from each table. But I don't know how to turn that into an Oracle statement. What I've got so far is this which doesn't deal with matching on row order:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A a 
USING 
(
  SELECT PROJECT_ID, DELETE_DATE
  FROM TABLE_B
  WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'
  ORDER BY DELETE_DATE ASC
) b ON (a.PROJECT_ID = b.PROJECT_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET a.LOAD_DATE = p.DELETE_DATE;
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be efficient as it's just a one-off job.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.  Order by has no impact in your merge statement.

Comment: Have you tried writing one query with two independent sub-queries in the FROM clause, each one bringing back data in the right order and also a ROWNUM virtual column, and joining on row num?  I'd try it myself but I don't have access to Oracle right now.

Comment: @PlanItMichael thanks, looks like Ponder Stibbons already did it! It does indeed work - I couldn't work out how to make the order take effect in a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This merge should do the work, as far as I properly understood your criteria:

```
merge into table_a ta
using (
  select pid project_id, id, delete_date
    from (
      select project_id pid, id, 
          row_number() over (partition by project_id order by id) rn
        from table_a) a
    join (
      select project_id pid, delete_date, 
          row_number() over (partition by project_id order by delete_date ) rn
        from table_b
        where delete_flag='Y') b using (pid, rn) ) tb 
on (ta.project_id = tb.project_id and ta.id = tb.id)
when matched then update
  set ta.load_date = tb.delete_date
```